# Can I instantiate a class and call the method

Tags: reactjs

I have one class which has state options imported from other file.

```
import heatChartOptions from './chartOptions/heatChartOptions';

class HeatContainer extends Component {

state = {
    options : heatChartOptions.options
}
// Render app with demo chart

loadHierarchy = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj,'heat');
}
}
```

Where heatChart options has object which call a method on click. But that method is available on our class. How to call that particular method from object.

```
 import HeatChart from '../heatChartContainer';

 export default {
axisColors: axisColors, 
options: {
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        height: 428
    },
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: axisColors.minColor,
        maxColor: axisColors.maxColor,
        labels: {
            style: style
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        padding: 2,
        headerFormat: '<div class="padding-0-10 padding-b-10"><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td colspan="2"><h5><strong>{point.name}</strong></h5></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">{point.type} Count: </td><td>{point.colorValue}</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">Device Count: </td><td>{point.value}</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table></div>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
                enabled: true,
                allowOverlap: true,
                style: {
                    fontFamily: "'univers', Arial, sans-serif",
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: "#FFF",
                    stoke: "#FFF"
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
  HeatChart.loadHierarchy({chartType:'momentaryDisturbance', name:this.name, previousLevel: this.previousLevel}) //this is the one I need to call

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I just called using HeatChart, Can I instantiate the heatchart class so that I can its method. Or is there any other way I can achieve this. Or I need functional component only to achieve this with the help of props.

Comment: You already have options you can invoke that click using `options.plotOptions...`

Comment: No, how can I call that method in my class. If I click, my class method is not calling, but if I put that method in heatChartOptions.js file then its calling.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I create a instance using my class import like below

```
new HeatChart().loadHierarchy({chartType:'momentaryDisturbance', name:this.name, previousLevel: this.previousLevel})
```